# count rows using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with timestamp data.
I want to count how many rows I have per minute, for example, given this table:

00:00:01 data1

00:00:21 data2

00:02:02 data3

00:02:10 data4

00:02:31 data5

the result should be [2,0, 3].
How can I do it?

Comment: I think pandas.resampler.count is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first convert your first column to a pd.Timedelta dtype, then set it into the index and use resample with count:

```
from io import StringIO
txt = StringIO("""00:00:01 data1

00:00:21 data2

00:02:02 data3

00:02:10 data4

00:02:31 data5""")

df = pd.read_csv(txt, names=['Time','Value'], sep='\s+')


df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

df = df.set_index('Time')

df_out = df.resample('T').count()

df_out
```

Output:

```
          Value
Time           
00:00:01      2
00:01:01      0
00:02:01      3
```

To list:

```
df_out['Value'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 3]
```